# Deriving other bindings of a vector addition while strictly adhering to the associative axiom thereof

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just found myself unable to understand
$$\alpha_1+(\alpha_2+(\alpha_3+\alpha_4))\implies(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)+(\alpha_3+\alpha_4)$$while **strictly adhering to** the axiom of vector addition$$\alpha+(\beta+\gamma)=(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma$$In other words, I want each step of derivation to have **only 3-term-wide changes** equivalent to the axiom above. Any comments or answers that can contribute to my understanding would be appreciated.

Comment: If you let $\alpha = \alpha_1$, $\beta = \alpha_2$ and $\gamma = \alpha_3 + \alpha_4$ then using the associativity relation moves you from the left hand side to the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get your desired equation from the axiom in *one step* by setting

- $\alpha=\alpha_1$
- $\beta=\alpha_2$
- $\gamma=\alpha_3+\alpha_4$