# Why does the associative property of vector addition imply a sum may be written as $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

In an effort to understand that a sum involving a number of vectors is independent of the way in which these vectors are associated, I've tried to derive other bindings of certain vector additions in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626575/deriving-other-bindings-of-a-vector-addition-while-strictly-adhering-to-the-asso). However, this is definitely **not a proof** because, in order to adequately support the proposition above, we need to consider **all the bindings of every single vector addition**. In conclusion, my question is, how can I be sure the associative property of vector addition imply that a sum may be written without confusion as $$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n.$$

Comment: Induct on the number of symbols.

Comment: @T.Bongers I think there are too many cases to consider in an inductive step. Is that possible?

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Associative_implies_generalized_associative

Comment: @T.Bongers The link was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand my answers? They are both different from the one in the link, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use structural induction, which is how induction should always be thought of anyway.

In this case, all you have to do is to prove that if the theorem holds for all smaller sums (namely fewer addition operations), then it holds for this sum too. How to do it? Well if the sum has no addition at all, you are trivially done. If it does, then regardless of the order of additions, one of it will be the last one, adding the sum on its left with the sum on its right. Under the assumption that the theorem holds for all smaller sums, the sums on its left and its right are both smaller than it (because the last addition operation is not in them) so the order of additions does not matter for them. So you get that the current sum if split between $c,d$ will be:

$(a+b+\cdots+c) + (d+e+\cdots+f+g)$

$ = \Big( ((a+b)+\cdots)+c \Big) + \Big( d+(e+(\cdots+(f+g))) \Big)$

$ = \Big( (((a+b)+\cdots)+c)+d \Big) + \Big( e+(\cdots+(f+g)) \Big)$

$ = \Big( ((((a+b)+\cdots)+c)+d)+e \Big) + \Big( \cdots+(f+g) \Big)$

$ \ddots$

Where each equality just uses one application of the associativity property. Eventually this proves that no matter which addition operation is chosen as the last one, the result is always the same as just performing the additions from left to right. Hence the theorem is true for the current sum too. Therefore by structural induction the theorem is true for all sums.

Answer (score 0):

Another method that gives an additional insight is to consider the sequence of addition operations as the internal nodes of a tree with the terms at the leaves. "$a+((b+c)+d)$" would correspond to:

```
  +
 / \
a   +
   / \
  +   d
 / \
b   c
```

Now the question is obviously equivalent to asking whether all possible binary trees with the terms at the leaves in the same order result in the same result computed at the root node. It is also easy to see now that associativity is nothing more than a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation) at an internal node. As in the other solution we use the standard strategy of finding a canonical form, namely the one with additions done from left to right. That corresponds to every internal node having its right subtree being a leaf, and we shall call the tree left-linear. So we have to prove that we can use rotations to make any tree left-linear.

Again we proceed by structural induction. The case where the tree has only a single node is trivial, so we only deal with the other case, where the root node will have two subtrees. If every smaller tree can be made left-linear by rotations (our induction hypothesis), we take the current tree, make the right subtree of the root node left-linear (by the induction hypothesis), and then apply a single rotation at the root to make the right subtree a leaf, and then make the left subtree left-linear (by the induction hypothesis), and the entire tree is now left-linear (establishing the induction step). Therefore by structural induction every binary tree can be made left-linear by rotations.